# error with "other-window" with "emacs-startup-hook"

Tags: emacs, emacs23

When I open emacs, I would like to see the following:

2 windows, left window is for editing the document and the right windows run the program "multi-term"

I tried to edit my ~/.emacs with:

```
(add-hook 'emacs-startup-hook 'other-window)
(add-hook 'emacs-startup-hook 'multi-term)
(add-hook 'emacs-startup-hook 'split-window-horizontally)
```

the last two commands work, i.e I get 2 windows, one in left and one in right and the left one runs multi-term. (Althought I wanna the converse). But the command

```
(add-hook 'emacs-startup-hook 'other-window)
```

doesn't work. I get

```
wrong number of arguments: other-window, 0
```

Why? I think I can do everything if I type a correct function name, if this function really works if I type it in Emacs with M-x function_name.

How could I resolve this problem?

Comment: I have try to google "  (add-hook 'emacs-startup-hook 'other-window) ", but no information for this.

Comment: I found that (multi-term) (other-window 1) (split-window-horizontally) in ~/.emacs can achieve what I wanna do, i.e the left one is the doc. I wanna to edit and the right one is multi-term. But If I type M-x multi-term M-x other-window M-x split-window-horizontally, I get two windows with the same buffer. Is there any difference between other-window 1 and other-window? I can't type M-x other-window 1 in emacs, I can only add this in ~/.emacs.

Answer (score 0):

The command `other-window` takes an argument, which you're not providing.  When you hit the keys <kbd>C-x n</kbd>, the argument is filled in for you automatically.  Try:

```
(add-hook 'emacs-startup-hook (lambda () (other-window 1)))
```

Or, you could mimic the keystroke by doing:

```
(add-hook 'emacs-startup-hook (lambda () (call-interactively 'other-window)))
```